# mysqli_stmt_num_rows keeps returning 0

Tags: php, mysqli

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Naam
    if (isset($_POST['anoniem'])) {
        $nameOK = true;
        $name = "Anoniem";
    }
    else if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $nameErr = "Vul uw naam in of vink het vakje 'Anoniem' aan.";
    }
    else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $nameOK = true;
    }

    //Review
    if (empty($_POST['review'])) {
        $reviewErr = "Vul uw review in";
    }
    else if (preg_match("/(kut|fuck|fucking)/i", $_POST['review'])) {
        $reviewErr = "Gelieve niet te vloeken in uw review";
    }
    else {
        $review = $_POST['review'];
        $reviewOK = true;
    }

    //Rating
    if (empty($_POST['rating'])) {
        $ratingErr = "Geef een cijfer";
    }
    else if (!is_numeric($_POST['rating'])) {
        $ratingErr = "Vul een getal in"; 
    }
    else {
        $rating = $_POST['rating'];
        $ratingOK = true;
    }
    //Opslaan naar DB

    if ($nameOK && $reviewOK && $ratingOK) {
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
        $date = date('d-m-Y G:i');
        $Dupe = false;
        $stmt = NULL;

        if ($name != "Anoniem") {
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE reviewer_name = ? AND review = ?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $name, $review);

            if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
                echo mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

                if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
                    $Dupe = true;
                    $DBnoti = "Dit review bestaat al, Review is niet opgeslagen.";
                }
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }
            else {
                echo "Er is een fout opgetreden.";
            }
        }

        if (!$Dupe) {
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO reviews (rating, review, reviewer_name, review_date) VALUE (?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isss", $rating, $name, $review, $date);

            if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                $DBnoti = "Review succesvol opgeslagen";
            } 
            else {
                $DBnoti = "Er is een fout opgetreden tijdens het opslaan. Review niet opgeslagen.";
            }
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
```

Whenever I try to check if the user input is already inserted into the database, `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)` keeps returning 0 and I have no idea how to fix it. It worked earlier before I used prepared statements, but when I tried to implement prepared statements to protect the database, it wouldn't work anymore.
`$conn` is the name of the variable from my connection to my database.
Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: if you checked for the real error as to why that was, you might out why that is. Then, update your post to contain what it was.

Comment: My code didn't give any errors.

Comment: That piece of code looks fine to me. Can you make sure that the values of `$name` and `$review` are as expected? You can check this by printing their values before binding them.

Comment: @pgngp When printing the values of `$name` and `$review` it gives the correct string entered in the form.

Comment: @DjordyKoert Can you comment out `mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);` and try again?

Comment: @pgngp It seems your solution worked. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @DjordyKoert That's great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try to change rating string s to **i**, you ask this to be numeric `if (!is_numeric($_POST['rating'])) {`  and in your code you use 4 times string.. your code:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $rating, $name, $review, $date);
```

check this [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)